# How to display total price amout by every other week in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm studing sum in Laravel. I woud like to display "total price" of the First week , the second week, the third week, the fourth week diffrently. And I also display This month's total price amount.

Could you teach me how to write controller code please?

```
public function total_price_amount_this_month()
    {
        $prices= PriceList::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('total_price_amount_this_month',compact('prices'));
    }

    public function the_first_week()
    {
        $prices= PriceList::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('the_first_week',compact('prices'));
    }
```

Here is my table.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to calculate the sum prices of latest 7 days you can do like this :

```
$price = PriceList::whereDate('time', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
                   ->sum('price');
print_r($price);
```

Or if you want to put the dates manually the use `whereBetween()`

Hope it will help u!

Edit: If want it manually

```
$from_date = //Whatever
$to_date = //Whatever
$price = PriceList::whereBetween('time', [$from_date, $to_date])
                   ->sum('price');
```

Thats what you have to do!

Comment: Thank you for answer. I see ... I have to select dates manually... Is there way to just open The_first_week.blade.php page and display the total price?

Comment: first slelect the dates(if manually by input) then calculate the sum of the prices and redirect in that desired blade with that  value what you already doing

Comment: Thank you for comment. Could you teach me code please ? How about the second week that is  2020/5/3 to 2020/5/9 ?